# False positive in SpotBugs (D'Oh! Nonsensical invocation - DMI_DOH)?

Tags: java, spotbugs

The code below is generating the SpotBugs warning, `"D'Oh! A nonsensical invocation of isNullOrEmpty(String) in com.myco.Launcher.validArguments() [Scary(7), Normal confidence]"` (DMI_DOH).

```java
public class Launcher {
    @Injected(name="-f", description="optional name of file")
    private static String filename;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (validArguments()) {
            ...
    }

    private boolean validArguments() {
        boolean result = true;
        if (com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty(Launcher.filename)) {
            result = false;
        }
        else if (...) {
            ...
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

`filename` is a value collected from the command line as I'm using a CLI library to set that value for me if/when it's supplied.  If the user doesn't supply the value on the command line, the field will be `null`.  My hunch is this is a false positive and I'll need to suppress this warning.  If not, please help me understand how this invocation is a blunder.

I removed the `static` modifier from the field and it appeared to resolve it.  It seems this warning is best suited for invocations such as:

```java
Strings.isNullOrEmpty("abcd");
```

That's a blunder. LOL!

Honestly, I don't see why having this field `static` is a mistake.  My CLI library sets it correctly either way.  And without the annotation, it's going to be `null` either way, but non-static somehow satisfies it?

Comment: You almost certainly do not want a static context here. Static and DI don't mix well, generally. Also, FindBugs isn't end-all-be-all - it's a suggestion of things to review for correctness. If you review it, and determine it's correct enough for you - move on.

Comment: Also, understand that you are using DI to inject the value of `filename` at runtime - but from compile time's perspective, the value of `filename` is always null. A static analysis tool, such as FindBugs/SpotBugs will flag this since it's unusual, and might indicate a programming error was made based on an assumption that `filename` may or may not be null at runtime - a contradiction to the code above. We know DI will work it's "magic" for you, but your tools may not understand this, understand it poorly or incompletely.

Comment: *"Honestly, I don't see why having this field static is a mistake."* - Consider what might happen if `Launcher.main` was called more than once; e.g. if you added another entrypoint that calls `Launcher.main` programatically.  (It maybe is not realistic in your use-case, but I've seen it ....)  Consider what happens if you wanted to write unit tests for your `Launcher` class that entailed calling `main` more than once (across all of the tests).  And consider SnakeDoc's point about `static` vs DI. The point is ... it **could be** a mistake.